Why are there few/no traditional japanese dishes made with rice noodles?
I was looking into Japanese dishes that I could cook for a friend with Celiac disease - so, no gluten.
I love making Ramen, and I know of course that Ramen is traditionally made with wheat noodles. But, I was wondering if there was a Japanese style of noodle similar to Ramen, but rice-based instead of wheat-based.
As it turns out, I'm either missing something, or the answer is no! There are plenty of other Japanese styles of noodles: Soba, Udon, and Somen, to name a few. However, each variety I found was either made of wheat flour or usually contains a bit of wheat flour mixed in.
There are also plenty of varieties of Rice noodles, but none of them seem to originate from Japan - Wikipedia doesn't have any rice noodle dishes listed from Japan.
Can anyone that knows more about noodles shed some light on this?

I’m voting to close this question because it's out of scope as defined in the [help].

Hello Will! Our site has a rather narrow scope. Questions like yours are fascinating to ask, but the problem is, they're difficult to answer - and it's even more difficult for non-specialists to distinguish between right and wrong answers. So, we're trying to stick to what we can answer as cooks, as opposed to creating just-so stories about the origins of human food culture.

Hello, I understand. However, @rumtscho you might want to take "The history of food and cooking" bullet point out of the help center if such questions are considered off-topic.

Looking at https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1921/are-questions-about-the-history-of-foods-and-cooking-off-topic and the history tag, I'm not confident this question should be considered off topic.
